# Need to interact with foreign IVR

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I need to interact with a foreign IVR programmatically.

The problem that I'm running into is that once into the foreign IVR, I will occasionally receive a busy signal for a particular feature if the foreign IVR's back-end is tied up.

To my knowledge, without using EAGI and writing a custom DSP in Perl, there's not really much I can do about this, right?  The Dial() application is going to think it succeeded, because it did (on the initial outbound dial).

I'm kind of stuck thinking about how I check to see if I'm *currently* getting a busy signal, even if the original Dial() succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control call flow after dial using AMI interface.

You also can create application using audiohooks(in c/c++) to do anything in background.

Using perl only method get voice is EAGI or JACK.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the only way.  I wish there was a way (without hacking Asterisk) to be able to use the dsp code at any given time.  Turns out though that my client didn't really need to go that far.

Comment: You can process using JACK. or you can ask someone to create event handler for you(~1000 cost task). your task is non-standart and no default way for it yet,sorry. To see how write similar code see busy detect in chan_dahdi.c and code of BackgroundDetect